# Animate the process of adding layers to a ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am starting to get familiar with `gganimate`, but I want to extend my gifs further.

For instance, I can throw a `frame` on one variable in `gganimate` but what if I want to animate the process of adding entirely new layers/geoms/variables?

Here's a standard `gganimate` example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, frame = cyl)) +
    geom_point()

gg_animate(p)
```

But what if I want the gif to animate:

```
# frame 1
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point()

# frame 2
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl)))

# frame 3
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl), size = wt))

# frame 4
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl), size = wt)) +
    labs(title = "MTCARS")
```

How might this be accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manually add a `frame` aesthetic to each layer, though it will include the legends for all of the frames immediately (Intentionally, I believe, to keep ratios/margins, etc. correct:

```
saveAnimate <-
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  # frame 1
  geom_point(aes(frame = 1)) +
  # frame 2
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl)
                 , frame = 2)
             ) +
  # frame 3
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl), size = wt
                 , frame = 3)) +
  # frame 4
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl), size = wt
                 , frame = 4)) +
  # I don't think I can add this one
  labs(title = "MTCARS")

gg_animate(saveAnimate)
```

[image]

If you want to be able to add things yourself, and even see how legends, titles, etc. move things around, you may need to step back to a lower-level package, and construct the images yourself. Here, I am using the `animation` package which allows you to loop through a series of plots, with no limitations (they need not be related at all, so can certainly show things moving the plot area around. Note that I believe this requires ImageMagick to be installed on your computer.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg))

toSave <- list(
  p + geom_point()
  , p + geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl)))
  , p + geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl), size = wt))
  , p + geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl), size = wt)) +
    labs(title = "MTCARS")
)

library(animation)

saveGIF(
  {lapply(toSave, print)}
  , "animationTest.gif"
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty slick. I don't think I've ever seen an animated display on SO before. I thought SO only displayed png files. Now we just need to slow it down a littel bit, but that would perhaps be another question.

Comment: The help for `saveGIF` points to `ani.options` which includes `interval` which sets the time each frame stays (in seconds). So, just adding `interval = 3` would get you 3 seconds per frame

Comment: Fo a moment it appeared you must have added code to hold the legends in a fixed format, but that impression went away as the page refreshed. Oh, never, mind... the upper one has that feature and the lower one does not.

Answer (score 2):

The `gganimate` commands in the earlier answers are deprecated as of 2021 and won't accomplish OP's task.

Building on Mark's code, you can now simply create a static ggplot object with multiple layered geoms and then add the `gganimate::transition_layers` function to create an animation that transitions from layer to layer within the static plot. Tweening functions like `enter_fade()` and `enter_grow()` control how elements change into and out of frames.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

anim <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  # Title
  labs(title = "MTCARS") +
  # Frame 1
  geom_point() +
  # Frame 2  
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl))) +
  # Frame 3
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl), size = wt)) +
  # gganimate functions
  transition_layers() + enter_fade() + enter_grow()

# Render animation
animate(anim)
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Great contribution. +1. The last frame is pointless. (although there are plenty of points drawn). The OP had intended to add a title here. Tried it - may be not that straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the accidental repeated `geom_point()`. Edited post to remove it and add a title, as OP specified. Adding a `labs(title = "")` call anywhere between the `ggplot()` call and `gganimate` functions seems to do it.

Answer (score 0):

the `animation` package doesn't force you to specify frames in the data. See the example at the bottom of this page [here](http://www.mattwinn.com/tools/HB95_2.html), where an animation is wrapped in a big `saveGIF()` function. You can specify the duration of individual frames and everything.

The drawback to this is that, unlike the nice gganimate functions, the basic frame-by-frame animation wont hold the plot dimensions/legend constant. But if you can hack your way into displaying exactly what you want for each frame, the basic animation package will serve you well.